# как определить рабочий день?

Tags: delphi

Есть таблица holiday, где заранее записаны не рабочие дни, т.т. выходные и праздничные дни:

```
id | holidaysdate
==========================
1 25.11.2017
2 26.11.2017
3 02.12.2017
4 03.12.2017
.....
И т.д.
```

Как определить следующий рабочий день после трех выходных?

```
function TForm2.isnotworkdaykaz: integer;
var
  work_day: TDate;
begin
  OracleSession1.Connected := True;

  odsHoliday.Close;
  odsHoliday.SetVariable('IN_DATE', date);
  odsHoliday.Open;

  work_day := odsHoliday.FieldByName('HOLIDAYDATE').AsDateTime;

  if work_day = 0 then
    Result := 0 // рабочий день
  else
    Result := 1;  // выходной/праздничный день

  OracleSession1.Connected := False;
end;
```

Comment: Вы хотите решение в виде хранимой процедуры или запроса к БД. Или производить вычисление на клиентском приложении в Делфи?

Comment: А как определить, какие нужны "три выходных"?

Comment: желательно на делфи

Comment: как определить три выходных? Допустим в таблице holiday указаны три дня 10.01.2018, 11.01.2018 и 12.01.2018 необходимо вывести после этих выходных рабочий день. На данный момент после трех дней выпадают еще и выходные суббота и воскресенье и в этом случае рабочим днем необходимо вывести 15.01.2018 день. И Т.Д.

Comment: *после трех дней выпадают еще и выходные суббота и воскресенье* у-у-у... может, есть смысл перестать экономить на данных ценой пухлого кода, и сделать наоборот - в таблице все праздники плюс все выходные? *Допустим в таблице holiday указаны три дня 10.01.2018, 11.01.2018 и 12.01.2018* Допустим, в таблице НЕ указаны такие выходные. Максимум два подряд. Что делать будем? причём и когда после них выходной, и когда пары с выходным после - нет... А так-то что - в процедуре находим три выходных подряд, а потом в цикле плюсим по одному дню, пока не наткнёмся на рабочий день

Comment: да так оно и тесть все выходные с учетом субботы и воскресенье

Comment: покажите в виде кода плеаззз)))